# How can I show regular price for a specific product category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, taxonomy-terms

How can I display the regular price and not discount price on my product listing for a specific category? It always shows me the discount price.

Here is my code:

```
function filter_woocommerce_get_regular_price() {
    global $product;
    if (is_product_category ('book-fair')) {
        return $product->get_regular_price();
    }
    return $product->get_sale_price();
}
```

I'm far from the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The hook `woocommerce_get_regular_price` is obsolete and deprecated… Try the following instead:

```
// Custom regular price for specific product categories
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'filter_woocommerce_product_get_price', 10, 2); 
function filter_woocommerce_product_get_price( $price, $product ) {

    if ( has_term( array('book-fair'), 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) && $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        return $product->get_regular_price();
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Thank you Loic, I have an error on website now, I don't found where is the problem on your code ?

Comment: oh I found thank you ! I show the good price on a product page not on a listing page, I will try to found, thank lot Loic

Comment: @Velphia My fault, there was a duplicated `(` that I have removed… Now If your product listing is not using the `WC_Product` method `get_price()` to get product prices, my code will not work.